# Sunspot Spatial Search Not Returning Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geohashing

I've just implemented the Sunspot gem into my application and I really like it except for the fact that when I do a location search it seems to be excluding some results. For example: I live in Columbus Ohio so if I search for "Columbus Ohio" my application translates that into a lat/lng and I do:

```
@search = (Skatepark.search {

  with(:coordinates).near lat, lng, :precision => 3
  fulltext text
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 15

})
```

This returns some records that are geocoded on the west side of columbus but none of my records that I have in my DB that are on the east side. Am I doing something wrong w/ my search?

You can  try it out for yourself at http://skateparks.co/search

If you search for "Columbus Ohio" you'll get totally different results than if you search for "Lancaster Ohio" which is only a few miles to the southeast.

Comment: Make sure the records (missing from search) have lat and lng values. Depending on where the data came from it could be as simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

This is because Sunspot depends on [gem 'pr_geohash'](https://github.com/masuidrive/pr_geohash) which generates the geospatial index.

A [geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) is a form of [z-order curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).

You are attempting to solve a [nearest neighbor problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) using this index, which by its nature can only produce **approximate** results. The author would have chosen this approach since Solr is designed to deal with large datasets, which [suffer from the curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

Depending on your requirements, perhaps you should try

1. a [siloless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_silo) solution eg. [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/docs/web_services/geosearch) (there are [several gems](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=freebase))
2. a [saas solution](https://simplegeo.com/)
3. a [spatial database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_database_systems),
4. a [geodatabase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodatabase#Implementations),
5. or your own [approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index#Spatial_Index)?

### Proposed Solution

Use [geojson](http://geojson.org/) objects for [cities, towns, & villages](http://www.freebase.com/view/location/citytown) rather than plain lat/long. Use [semantic autocompletion](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.7710&rep=rep1&type=pdf) so that users can select the polygon directly from Freebase. (Interface example: [Quora](http://www.quora.com/) search box) This way, all results in the requested city will be returned as you are now doing a polygonal bounding search rather than a radial search.

I urge you to make your data available as Freebase [Locations](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/location) where the parent is a [City/Town/Village](http://www.freebase.com/view/location/citytown) if this is at all possible given your business model. Turns out there is both a [location type](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/skatepark) and a [location topic](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/skatepark/-/base/skateboarding/type_of_skateboarding_location/skateboarding_location_of_this_type) all ready for you.

#### Update 1

I notice that you're on Heroku.

If you have a dedicated db you could use [PostGIS](http://twitter.com/#!/heroku/status/12245609985).

If not, read [How do you do GIS queries on Heroku using the shared database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413919/how-do-you-do-gis-queries-on-heroku-using-the-shared-database)